# How does UPS Tracking work?

Tags: magento-1.8, ups, shipment-tracking

I want to know how does the Tracking work for UPS Shipping? Searched a lot but they will always redirect me to paid extensions.

**UPDATE** :  As **ForMat** described, will magento automatically receive UPS Tracking Number after "Create Packages"  operation? PF screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** After downloading the latest Magento CE 1.9.1 User Guide I found that managing UPS shipments and printing lables (with tracking) may be possible after all. But it may depend on which country you're from.

> Magento connects to the shipping carrier, creates the order in its
>   system, and receives a shipping label and tracking number for each
>   package. If a shipping label is successfully created, the new shipment
>   is saved and the shipping label is available for printing. A tracking
>   number appears in the Shipping and Tracking Information section.

You can download the latest User Guide from [this page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/user-guide-download) and find out all about shipping starting at page 575.

*Off topic:* I must say that Magento is doing a pretty good job on improving the User Guide!

---

<strike>I'm not sure what you mean by "the Tracking" but as far as I know the UPS Shipping Module that comes standard with Magento CE is only for generating shipping rate quotes. It calculates and presents the applicable shipping rate to the customer during checkout, based on locations and settings in `System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > UPS`.</strike>

To my knowledge it does not manage actual shipments, nor does it generate any lables for printing or barcodes for tracking. You would need a (paid) extension for that.

Comment: Thanks, so UPS will provide tracking number(offline) before creating shipment?

Comment: I believe this is done automatically when creating a package during lable generation (see quote from User Guide page 597 which I just added to my answer). I have not used UPS myself, this is what I understand from the User Guide...

Comment: ForMat,Still one doubt over 'Custom Value'. Can you clarify what is 'Custom Value' as displayed in the screen shot? Is it mandatory to be filled?

Comment: I'm not sure, since I don't use UPS myself. But please note that is says `Customs Value` with an 's'. So I would think this is the total value of all items in your shipment and it determines how much import duty the package recipient must pay. You can read more about this [on the UPS website](https://www.ups.com/content/nl/en/resources/sri/customs-value.html).